# Implementing GetLocalResource()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, internationalization, resources

if I create a resource `Test.resx` I can access it from a Razor view:

```
@Test.Hello
```

but quite often I need to use resources in Javascript files.  Because I cannot embed Razor in Javascript files I typically grab whatever I need in the page and use it in the script, sort of like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Hello = '@Test.Hello';
</script>
<script src="Test.js"></script>
```

then in the `Test.js` I can use it:

```
alert(Hello);
```

...but rather than making a whole lot of references:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Hello = '@Test.Hello';
    var How = '@Test.How';
    var Are = '@Test.Are';
    var You = '@Test.You';
</script>
```

I'd like to grab the contents of the whole resource file and create a Javascript object with them, so often I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Resources = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ResX('Test')));
</script>
```

but this presents a problem... the function ResX, defined (more or less) like this:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ResX(string source)
    {
        source = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}.resx"
            , HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.ToString()
            , @"MyResourceFolder"
            , source
            );

        var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        IDictionaryEnumerator dn = (new ResXResourceReader(source)).GetEnumerator();
        ...
    }
```

now needs to know the location of my resource files.  what's worse, it will specifically use the fallback resource, such that if my client is German, it will ignore the `Test.de.resx`.

Now, I know I can just compose the file name properly, but in the same way that `GetlLocalResourceObject()` knows exactly which file to get, I should be able to call some function that returns the correct path.

So my question is: is there a method I could call that would give me the path of the local resource file (whatever file GetLocalResourceObject would use)?

Apropos, of the above, where should I be placing my resource files in an MVC 5 project?

Comment: did you consider using a library like http://code52.org/aspnet-internationalization/? This tool create's a javascript file containing all resources during runtime (and does other i18n things)...

Comment: wow, that's awesome.  I may not care to figure this out if I just implement that package.  all the same I'll leave the question open as it may attract an answer

Comment: pity the google translate API is no longer available free.  the Zeta Resource Editor no longer works.  would have been nice.  but then, their translations suck.  I need to have my stuff translated by humans

Comment: I use resharper for localization (you can create resources from strings very straightforward) and ResX to manage the translations (manually). This is not the perfect solution, but works.